# How to use [binder] in K?

Tags: kframework

I have syntax:

```
syntax Process ::= KVar "(" KVar ")" "." Process  [binder]
                 | "new" KVar "." Process         [binder]
syntax Program ::= KVar "(" KVarVec ")" "=" Process [binder]
syntax KVarVec ::= KVar | KVar "," KVarVec
```

The two syntax has three productions that bind differently:

1. `a(x).P`, where `x` is bound in `P`, but `a` is a name that isn't being bound by that term.
2. `new a.P` binds `a` in `P` like a lambda.
3. `f(a,b,c) = P` binds a vector `a,b,c` of `KVar` in `P`. Each `KVar` in the vector is supposed to be bound in `P`.

How can I tell `binder` to bind specific variables in a production? Is there something like `binder(2)` to tell it that the second `KVar` is supposed to be bound? what if its several `KVar`s defined by another syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently one of the limitations of the binder attribute is that the variable bound must be the first nonterminal in the production, and the term that it is bound in must be the last nonterminal. Feel free to make a feature request for the generalization you propose on GitHub and I'll get to it at some point. Might not be right away though.